# React Js Hooks+Router vs Redux+Router which one would be better to develop a app from scratch

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js. But I got confused with react hooks and react-redux. I am used to developing a UI with bootstrap. I have gone through [react boostrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/). So I am confused about using React Hooks as in  react-bootstrap all the components of bootstrap are in React Hooks. So for developing the application from scratch in bootstrap, I should go for React Hooks?. So what's the point of Redux now at this stage. Can I ignored React-Redux for now?

where should I learn a proper routing related to react Hooks & react Redux?

PS: I am using latest version of react js i.e 16.12.0

Comment: Sorry, but your questions are too broad and/or opinion-based for SO. You've asked several far-ranging questions without much context and which are mostly a matter of prerogative. We mostly work with code around here.

Comment: yeah true. It's mostly with coding firm but I believe code is logical chunks of thoughts. Here is I am confused with my thoughts. i want help to understand React js Architecture so that I can be able to migrate traditional UI based on Java JSP Application into React Js Application. As Traditional UI application have complexity I want to understand first where should I begin with. I want to use Routing in React. It can be done ia both i.e via Redux and via Hooks. Which should I prefer where should i pick up

Comment: I gave a highly opinionated answer to an opinionated question, oops! I want to highlight how React-Redux is actually built on top of context, and how hook-based APIs vs component-based APIs are a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Redux` is a surprisingly simple and light-weight library for managing an immutable, JS object that we call our state. It can't do much more than that. To make `Redux` useful in `React` applications, we rely on the library `React-Redux`. Under the hood, `React-Redux` actually uses `React`'s context, and it also now provides a hook-based API. It's not hooks vs redux, but rather *do I want hooks* and *do I also want `Redux` and `React-Redux`*?

[Here is the official explanation on how `React-Redux` adds `Redux` functionality to `React`'s context.](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux/#how-does-redux-compare-to-the-react-context-api)

A lot of `React` developers still assume `Redux` is a must, but that's really no longer true. Before context came along, there was no elegant solution native to `React` for managing large, centralized state. We have that now!

You'll know you need `Redux`+`React-Redux` when you are managing a complex state that can be updated from many places, or you want to dispatch hundreds of unique actions, or you need to handle lots of side-effects, or custom middleware must intercept actions etc. It's a lot of complexity and boilerplate that only fits when you have a huge, complex application.

`React-Router` and `React-Router-DOM` don't care if you're using `Redux`+`React-Redux`, if you're only using context, or if you're writing a completely stateless application. The API for routing supports both components, e.g. `<Route path="/some/path" />` and hooks. You can use whichever one you prefer. [The documentation for React-Router lives here.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) [And this is an example of routing with or without hooks.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)

The traditional pattern of higher-order components vs hooks is an architectural decision that developers must make on their own. When we use hooks for accessing state and/or context, our components become very aware of the state of our application. When `React-Redux`'s connect was the primary vehicle for accessing state, a component was always insulated from those details. For a smaller or learner project, I would not sweat these details. When you have an older, larger codebase using `React-Redux`, you'll see advantages of not using hooks to select from state.